# How to build a dynamic string in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
      message = "uploaded the file.... "
```

I want to include the filename and link off to the file. currently I have:

```
      message = "uploaded the file #{  link_to "#{feed_item.feeded.file_file_name}", '/test'   }""
```

As you can see that's pretty messy. Is there a cleaner way to write this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
message = "uploaded the file #{link_to(feed_item.feeded.file_file_name, '/test')}"
```

IMO the parens make it more readable when it's embedded like this.